# How to serialize double linked list in Python

Tags: python, json, data-structures, linked-list

I have a method-free Python class which is implemented as a double-linked list node:

```
class DataNode:
    def __init__(self, my_value):
        self.my_value = my_value
        
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
```

After initializing a number of DataNode instances, there are put in the list and linked:

```
# Suppose data_nodes is already filled with DataNode elements
for e1, e2 in zip(data_nodes, data_nodes[1:]):
    e1.next = e2
    e2.prev = e1
```

My question is: What would be the best way to serialize this list to .json? In other words, **how plausible would it be to write a somewhat of generalized encoder for double-linked lists?** In my program I have a number of classes implemented this way - it seems a bit wasteful to write a custom encoder for the each double-linked node class:

```
class DataNodeEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return {'my_value': o.my_value}
 
class DataNode2Encoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return {'my_other_value1': o.my_other_value1,
                'my_other_value2': o.my_other_value2}
```

Comment: Why don't you just serialise it as a list, maybe with a type tag? Preserving the LL structure seems like a waste – it will at least require an emulation of references/pointers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi or an absurdly nested JSON for any non-trivial list :) But yeah as a JSON array makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought about whether nesting is sufficient – but I'm sure for a doubly-linked list it's not. Once one settles for serialising a doubly-linked list as a singly-linked list, an even more suitable format can be chosen as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I could serialize it as list, but I would still need to write a custom encoder then for each LL - I have a number of them in my code

Comment: @MarkLumar That are two unrelated problems, aren't they? "How to handle X similar types of objects without separate encoder" and "How to encode LL types". The first part is really hard to focus on when there's only one type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would serialise as standard list, and then encode it from list back to doubly linked list. You could make a constructor for a `DataList` class that can take a list or separate values as argument(s), and will create the doubly linked list. I would use a sentinel node to keep the code simple.

Add an `__iter__` method that will iterate the values (not the node objects). This way you can easily convert a doubly linked list to a list, and from there to JSON.

Here is the code:

```
class DataNode:
    def __init__(self, my_value, prev=None, nxt=None):
        self.my_value = my_value
        self.prev = prev
        if prev:
            prev.next = self
        self.next = nxt
        if nxt:
            nxt.prev = self
    
class DataList(DataNode):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        super().__init__(None, self, self)  # Sentinel node
        # Support a single argument that is a list or tuple
        if len(values) == 1 and type(values[0]) in (list, tuple):
            values = values[0]
        for value in values:
            self.append(value)

    def append(self, my_value):
        DataNode(my_value, self.prev, self)
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.next
        while node != self:
            yield node.my_value
            node = node.next
```

Here are some example uses:

```
# Create the doubly linked list from some given values
lst = DataList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
# Add a few more
lst.append(7).append(8)
# Get as standard list of values (not nodes)
print(list(lst))
# Get as JSON:
import json
print(json.dumps(list(lst)))
# Build from JSON:
lst = DataList(json.loads("[2,3,5,7,11]"))
# Print the values
print(*lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each node a unique Id. And use a custom serializer and deserializer to regenerate references as such. Mark the reference values so you can rebuild the list afterwards, with this you should be able to go through the list and generate the first part of the JSON and then include the references:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "myValue": "lorem ipsum",
  "next": {
    "$id": "2",
    "myValue": "lorem ipsum",
    "next": {
      "$id": "3",
      "myValue": "lorem ipsum",
      "next": {
        "$id": "4",
        "myValue": "lorem ipsum",
      },
      "prev": {
        "$ref": "2"          
      }
    },
    "prev": {
      "$ref": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

This can be done in two passes. One setting the next elements and one backreferencing prev elements where they exist. This is a way to keep your linked list in JSON. However, if it is not necessary to preserve the LL structure. You could also serialize it to a regular array and rebuild the linked list afterward.